# Best way to store chess piece locations to easily lookup a location given a piece or a piece given a location using object oriented design principles

Tags: c#, dictionary, oop, design-patterns, chess

I'm currently working on a OO representation of a simplified chess game. Most of it is straightforward enough but one design decision I'm a little unsure about is the relationship between the chessBoard and pieces. **The bottom line is I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent the chessboard / piece relationship so that I can easily and efficiently query "given a spot, is there a piece here" and "given a piece, what spot is it on"?**

Currently, the Piece class stores both their own location (using a Spot class) and a reference to the Board class. The board class represents the board as a Dictionary<Spot, Piece> (*the simplified game only has a few pieces so it felt unnecessary to store a mostly empty array of N by M spots like other examples I've seen*) to track what spots on the board have what pieces on them. This is useful and seems intuitive to me since the piece can use the reference to the board when trying to move and ask "is there anyone at this spot?" and it can return the piece if any that is on a given spot. Similarly, in order to move the piece I need to know where it currently is and storing the location on the piece itself seems like a good OO approach.

**The part where I'm running into some questions / trouble is how to keep those values in sync** such that if I call (public method) Board.MovePiece() or (private setter) Piece.CurrentPosition = new spot() both Piece.CurrentPosition and the Board's Dictionary<Spot, Piece> are updated properly. Keeping everything as private as possible while making sure that calling a method on either the board or the piece while keeping the other class in sync is very tricky if not impossible. If C# had friend classes like C++ I could just make the Board a friend of the Piece then they could set each other's private vars no problem (I'm aware of internal which improves things but I don't think it prevents other code in the project from theoretically calling stuff it shouldn't). Right now my solution to this is a custom setter on the piece.CurrentPosition property so that every call to change it results in the correct call to public board members (which absolutely works) but I feel like I could do better. The biggest risk is the board methods are public and could be called outside the piece class and thus not update the piece location but I'm not a huge fan of the redundancy / slight complexity smell the code has currently.

Here's a simplified look at my code:

```
public class Board : IBoard
    {
        private uint _width;
        private uint _height;
        private Dictionary<Spot, Piece> _pieceLocations;

        public Board(uint width, uint height)
        {
            _width = width;
            _height = height;

            _pieceLocations = new Dictionary<Spot, Piece>();
        }

        // heavily used by piece when determining legal moves, what pieces and free spaces are in range etc.
        public Piece CheckSpot(Spot spot)
        {
            Piece piece;
            if (_pieceLocations.TryGetValue(transformSpot(spot), out piece))
            {
                return piece;
            }
            return null;
        }
 
        /// remove instead of null to potentially optimize space a bit
        public bool RemovePiece(Spot spot)
        {
            if (spot != null)
            {
                return _pieceLocations.Remove(transformSpot(spot));
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// This function will simply attempt to just move the piece to the specified destination.
        /// It's up to the caller to make sure the move is a valid chess move, etc
        public Spot MovePiece(Spot destination, Piece pieceToBeMoved)
        {
            // remove piece from current position
            // note the need to have current position here
            RemovePiece(pieceToBeMoved.CurrentPosition);

            // attempt to place at and return new position
            return PlacePiece(destination, pieceToBeMoved);
        }

        /// Simply places piece at specified destination if not occupied by another piece
        private Spot PlacePiece(Spot destination, Piece pieceToPlace)
        {
            var transformedDestination = transformSpot(destination);

            //business logic to check for stuff like a piece already at destination

            _pieceLocations.Add(transformedDestination, pieceToPlace);

            return transformedDestination;
        }
```

Note transformSpot just makes sure coordinates are not out of bounds and "wraps them around" to be within board dimensions if need be.

```
public abstract class Piece : IPiece
    {
        protected IBoard _board;
        public ColorType Color { get; protected set; }
        private Spot _currentPosition;

        public Piece(ColorType color, Spot currentPosition, IBoard board)
        {
            _board = board;
            Color = color;
            CurrentPosition = currentPosition ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currentPosition), "When creating a piece you must specify a location");
        }

        public Spot CurrentPosition { 
            get { return _currentPosition; } 

            // I wanted to make sure that the piece's current position was always in sync with the board.
            // Calling <Board> functinos here seemed like a reasonable approach.
            protected set {

                // if position is being set to null remove from board
                if (value == null)
                {
                    _board.RemovePiece(_currentPosition);
                    _currentPosition = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    _currentPosition = _board.MovePiece(value, this);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Move()
        { 
            // note that I now need the current position to figure out where I can go etc.
            
            // insert logic to determine where we can move using chess rules etc.
            var destination = new Spot(x,y);

            // if spot is occupied remove piece
            var occupyingPiece = _board.CheckSpot(destination);
            if (occupyingPiece != null)
            {
                occupyingPiece.RemovePiece();
            }

            // call custom setter which in turn updates board to move piece from current spot to destination
            CurrentPosition = destination;
        }

        public void RemovePiece()
        {
            // call custom setter which in turn updates board to remove piece
            CurrentPosition = null;
        }
```

And some super rough pseudo code for the main driver

```
            List<Piece> whitePieces = generateWhitePieces();
            List<Piece> blackPieces = generateBlackPieces();

            while (gameActive)
            {

                //somehow determine which piece to move
                var pieceToMove = whitePieces.PickPiece();

                // could pass and store CurrentPosition at this level but if it's not stored on the piece or easily 
                // accessible from the board but feels slightly icky
                pieceToMove.Move();

                pieceToMove = blackPieces.PickPiece();

                pieceToMove.Move();
                // etc.

            }
```

Again, main flaw on top of some possibly unneeded complexity seems to be that Board.MovePiece() needs to be public for Piece to call it but that means anyone can also call MovePiece() and move something on the board without updating the piece.

**Possible solutions I have considered:**

I'm totally overthinking this and this is a fairly reasonable approach.

- having the piece own its own location feels right, just wish I had better access modifiers to protect sensitive values but allow friends to change them (I'm aware of internal but doesn't seem to solve my issues fully)

I could just remove currentPos and:

- have the board class maintain a Dictionary<Piece, Spot>

This feels like simply shifting the issue and having board maintain two dictionaries of essentially the same info in different orders feels silly, but at least it tightly couples the data together and allows the board to be the "authority" on where everything is. Leaning towards this but have a feeling this could be optimized somehow with the right data structure

- have the main driver / game class maintain a dictionary / tuple list of pieces and their current position and have the Piece.Move() pass back info on where the board tells them they are now.

Again this just feels like we're shifting the issue but even more so. On the other hand I can kinda see the rationale for the game to want to keep track of pieces but that still feels pretty anti OO and I'd probably prefer keeping this to the Board as described above.

In theory could also

- Just make current position setter public so Board could change it directly and add some complex checks in both the Board functions and the Piece.CurrentPosition setter to make sure if one is changed so is the other.

Feels much worse and adds more complexities / risks than it solves in my opinion. If it weren't for this issue CurrentPosition should have a private setter.

Anyway would very much appreciate any feedback / insight!

EDIT: to be clear I'm assuming that the piece class owns its logic when it comes to how it can move, and uses the state of the board to determine what spaces it can move to. Something like Piece.DetermineMove(). Specifically the piece needs to know where it is and what pieces if any are on the spaces it can move to, pieces that threaten it, etc.

If that's a poor design I'm all ears but I have a hard time believing that a Piece class shouldn't own its own movement logic in an OOP design.

Comment: First, I would ask myself if the extra redundancy/complexity is really necessary or if a simple (linear) search would be sufficient for one of the two possible queries.

Comment: That's a very valid question but I don't think that's really a good extensible / long term design decision. To be clear you're suggesting I just grab the Dictionary<Spot, Piece> and iterate through the entries until a piece finds itself? I see your point but I'm trying to demonstrate good design practice and this feels naive.

Comment: Yes, this was my first idea. If there are only few pieces, this will be hard to beat by a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: Assuming I ignore the space being doubled for a second and add the inverted Dictionary<Piece, Spot> do you think the extra add / remove steps required for the maintenance of the second dict would still overshadow the O(N) complexity of searching the list every time for piece location? This feels like it gets into the weeds of implementation details and compiler optimizations but my gut says anything greater than 2-3 pieces starts to drag compared to just maintaining the second dict.

Comment: That said there is value in reducing complexity and space usage I guess (though again we are assuming the dicts contain very few entries). On paper though retrieval goes from time O(1) and space O(n) with two dicts to time O(n) and still space O(n) if we just search the one. Maybe the clock times favor the search approach but on paper I'm not convinced we get too much outside of simplicity and better ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Opinions are going to be thick on this one, and there's really no absolutely correct answer. Each will have pros and cons, some of which you might not find out until much later on in development. That being said, here's mine. :)

What you really want to do is ensure that there is only one method to *do* any operation in your application, and only one place that *biblical data* is stored in the application (religious connotations aside, biblical meaning "true").

You can start with logical objects (in your domain) and attempt to place this one method into the object that it makes sense for. If it doesn't make sense, then you might need a different [mental] model.

You've started with `Board`, `Piece` and `Spot` and I like this so far. Since we want to keep the data for a location of a piece in *one place*, I think we want to do that at the *board level*, because it will make movement easier (a piece won't have to go "up" to the board and back "down" to another piece).

This means a `Piece` won't have a `Spot` property, only a type (knight, bishop, etc) and ColorType (white/black). The board will have the dictionary for the pieces with the `Spot` as the key (it's a good key - there can only be one piece on a square). This makes a lot of the logic easier. Moving a piece means taking it out of the dict and putting it back in at the destination:

```
// Move attempt method might look like this:

Piece thisPiece = ... ;
Spot old = (1, 1); // origin .. 
Spot new = (2, 2); // .. destination

// do some validation
if (pieces.Contains(new) && pieces[new].color == thisPiece.color)
    throw new SpotOccupiedByFriendlyPieceAndThisIsntACastleException(); 

// capture a piece
if (pieces.Contains(new) && pieces[new].color != thisPiece.color)
{
    pieces.Remove(new);
}
pieces.Remove(old); // move the old piece from "old"...
pieces.Add(new, thisPiece); //... to "new"
```

By putting all the pieces in a `Dictionary<Spot, Piece>` at the board level, there's only one collection that holds the pieces-to-spots relationship (the board owns it), and the board can perform all the logic it needs to.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion that I keep the logic to actually move pieces and the representation of where they are on the board within the Board class itself but this doesn't address the fundamental problem I have: how would the board class efficiently determine the location of given piece with only a Dictionary<Spot, Piece> ?




In my model let's say I keep all the logic for determining what move to make in a Piece.DecideWhereToMove() function. That function needs to ask the board two different questions: "What's on space X, Y?" and "Where am I?"

Comment: I can easily answer the first question with the  Dictionary<Spot, Piece> via the existing Board.CheckSpot(Spot spot) as shown above. But if I keep everything in the board class I also need something like Board.GetPieceLocation(Piece) which returns the spot a piece is on. Ideas I've come across include a second dictionary but inversed (so Dictionary<Piece, Spot> ) but that has some drawbacks in doubling storage and having to maintain two dicts. Another suggestion is to just linearly iterate through the existing dictionary until we blindly find the piece we're looking for but that feels naive.

Comment: In my model above, you never need to "find a spot for a given piece", but instead "find a piece for a given spot". The piece shouldn't know where to move, or really have any understanding of a board state. That data is "above its pay grade". The board should perform that work.

Comment: It's (in general) really bad to duplicate data in two dicts - you open yourself up to a class of desync bugs. What I'm getting at is that in chess, we never need to get a piece in the abstract (ie, we never say "what spot is my king on"), we only get the piece starting from a spot ("what is on (1,1)?"). Let me put it another way - when you ask "how would the board class efficiently determine the location of given piece?", my response is "the board should never need to". Pieces don't exist without a spot, and we start every operation from a spot (move to, capture at, evaluate to-from).

Comment: Are you suggesting that the Piece shouldn't own its own movement logic (pawns can move like this, kings can do that, etc) ? If I understand correctly then the board would not only own the state of the board but also encapsulate all the movement abilities of every piece type and that feels wrong in for something that's meant to be OOP in nature. Perhaps if you gave an example of how a piece would call the board method to move it I'd understand better. Specifically I want to understand where 

Spot old and 
Spot new

come from / are populated from if not passed by piece.

Comment: > we never say "what spot is my king on"

I'm not so sure about this. As a human I look at my pieces, see where they can move, then pick a piece and a destination for that piece. In this model I'd have a player class with a list of pieces. If I were to brute force picking the best move I'd iterate on every piece I owned then every move it could make, score it, then pick the best move. But to do that the piece has to know where it is to tell the player all the moves it can make (again unless for some reason the piece class doesn't own the rules it moves by).

Comment: I would subclass pieces with an abstract piece parent, and have pieces return a List of valid spots they can move to when given a spot as a parameter. Then the board can both evaluate the current location (or iterate through the list of valid spots for a piece and pass that board state to an evaluation method elsewhere). The board is the container for the piece/spots - A piece shouldn't know about other pieces (in my opinion - and it's just an opinion).